# Is there any difference between these sentences? "will" vs "would"

Tags: will-would

Is there any difference between these sentences?

> Ticket will be reopened once the same issue **will** be noticed.
>
> Ticket will be reopened once the same issue **would** be noticed.

Are they correct in terms of grammar?

Comment: Actually, neither of these is correct.  We say **the** ticket (or **a** ticket) will be reopened once the same issue **is** noticed.  We use the present tense, **is noticed**, because the issue actually has to be noticed before the ticket is opened - the noticing can't still be in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would you please provide additional links, which explain this in more detail?

Comment: Neither of these sentences makes sense to me. Unless the sentence makes sense it is impossible to say which version is correct. Please could you provide some context to explain what you are trying to say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Once* in the way you are using it can only follow these patterns:

> Once the guard walked away, I snuck past him. (Once [past], [past])
>
> > I snuck past the guard once he walked away. ([past] once [past])
>
> Once the guard walks away, I will sneak past him. (Once [present], [future])
>
> > I will sneak past the guard once he walks away. ([future] once [present]).

and with *would* (you can "flip" these like above as well):

> Once the guard walks away, I would sneak past him.  (Would here = should, this can be used by someone suggesting this to someone else - imagine an implied "if I were you" at the end of this.)
>
> Once the guard walked away, I would sneak past him.  (This is "will in the past")

Nothing else makes sense.